# Need to add new column in pandas data frame based on some rule on a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I have a data frame in Pandas (using Python 3.7) as shown below:

```
print("DATA FRAME DATA= \n",bin_data_df_sorted.head(5))
# OUTPUT:
# DATA FRAME DATA= 
#     actuals  probability
# 0      0.0     0.116375
# 1      0.0     0.239069
# 2      1.0     0.591988
# 3      0.0     0.273709
# 4      1.0     0.929855
```

I need to add extra column named 'bucket' such that:

```
If probability value in between (0,0.1), then bucket=1
If probability value in between (0.1,0.2), then bucket=2
If probability value in between (0.2,0.3), then bucket=3
If probability value in between (0.3,0.4), then bucket=4
If probability value in between (0.4,0.5), then bucket=5
If probability value in between (0.5,0.6), then bucket=6
If probability value in between (0.6,0.7), then bucket=7
If probability value in between (0.7,0.8), then bucket=8
If probability value in between (0.8,0.9), then bucket=9
If probability value in between (0.9,1), then bucket=10
```

So, the output should look like this:

```
#     actuals  probability   bucket
# 0      0.0     0.116375      2
# 1      0.0     0.239069      3   
# 2      1.0     0.591988      6
# 3      0.0     0.273709      3
# 4      1.0     0.929855      10
```

How can we do it?

NOTE:  I have tried below code but it is not working correctly.

```
> for val in bin_data_df_sorted['probability']:
>     if val >= 0.0 and val <=0.1:
>         bin_data_df_sorted['bucket']=1
>     elif val > 0.1 and val <=0.2:
>         bin_data_df_sorted['bucket']=2
>     elif val > 0.2 and val <=0.3:
>         bin_data_df_sorted['bucket']=3
and so on..
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
import numpy as np
bins = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
df['bucket'] = pd.cut(df.probability, bins, labels=(bins*10)[1:])

   actuals  probability bucket
0      0.0     0.116375    2.0
1      0.0     0.239069    3.0
2      1.0     0.591988    6.0
3      0.0     0.273709    3.0
4      1.0     0.929855   10.0
```

---

**Details**

`pd.cut` bins values from a sequence into discrete intervals. So you need to specify some criteria to bin by. You can do:

```
bins = np.arange(0,1.1, 0.1)
# array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

And some labels for the returned bins, which in this case can be generated using the same `bins`:

```
(bins*10)[1:]
# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
```

Comment: Now, if I need to plot a histogram such that x-axis = Bucket Number (i.e 1 to 10) and y-axis = Sum of 'Actuals' . Then How can I do that?

Comment: Try `df.groupby('bucket').actuals.sum().plot(kind='bar')` @Bhuvi007